# Retrieving node per siblings with a specific id with xpath

Tags: html, xpath

Suppose I have an html like this:

```html
<node>
       <child class="color" id="red"></child>
</node>
<node>
       <child class="ok"></child>
</node>
<node>
       <child class="ok"></child>
</node>
<node>
       <child class="color" id="blue"></child>
</node>
<node>
       <child class="ok"></child>
</node>
```

I would like to have an output of:

```
red

red

blue
```

That is, generate me the info of the COLOR nodes per `<child>` they have with `class="ok"`

What I tried:

```html
//child[@class="ok"]/parent::node/preceding-sibling::*[child::*[@class="color"]][1]
```

intuitively thinking that I will get a "node#" node per child with "ok", but it doesn't work.

Comment: Your html doesn't seem to be valid. Where is closing `</child>` for the `<child class="color" id="red">`

Comment: @svasa think its ok now

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, this can't be done using pure XPath 1.0. Using higher version of XPath which support FLWOR, you can do as follow :

```
for $node in //node[child/@class='ok']
return $node/preceding-sibling::node[child/@id][1]/child/@id
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/745a9b7e5f3ffa7f5f3c1d60a830b988)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
red
red
blue
```